# referencing dictionary variable value in ansible task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Team,
I have a task where am trying to reference value from a dictionary defined in my values file. but getting below error, any hint? am doing this exercise to use this reference in my other tasks later but first debug step itself is failing.

I referred this link [ansible dict reference][1]

values.yaml

```
loop_device: "loop"
available_device_default_config:
  - device: any
    partitions:
      - number: 1
        start: 0%
        end: 100%
        storage_class: services
```

task

```
- name: lookup dictionary vars
    debug:
      var: available_device_default_config.device
```

task output error

```
34  TASK [local_volume_mount : lookup dictionary vars] *****************************
  Wednesday 28 April 2021  21:51:34 +0000 (0:00:04.915)       0:00:05.052 ******* 
  ok: [node1] => {
      "available_device_default_config.device": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
  }
```

expected output:

```
ok: [node1] => {
      "any"
  }
```

I tried below but no luck

`var: "{{ available_device_default_config.device }}"`

`var: "{{ available_device_default_config['device'] }}"`

Comment: I added expected output that i was able to acheive with static values baked into task directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `available_device_default_config` is defined as a list of dicts. So you cannot access the property `device` directly, because it is a property of the first item in `available_device_default_config`. You need to look into it via `available_device_default_config[0]`

```
- name: "set facts"
  set_fact:
    available_device_default_config:
      - device: any
        partitions:
          - number: 1
            start: 0%
            end: 100%
            storage_class: services

- name: "lookup dictionary vars"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ available_device_default_config }}"

- name: "lookup dictionary vars"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ available_device_default_config[0].device }}"
```

The result would be

```
TASK [set facts] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [lookup dictionary vars] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - device: any
    partitions:
    - end: 100%
      number: 1
      start: 0%
      storage_class: services

TASK [lookup dictionary vars] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: any
```

Comment: can you please also hint how could just search with name instead of index 0? like for device value what is subkey value?